Why can't countries simply reclassify any part of someone else's land as an overseas territory to avoid decolonization processes?
In the mid-20th century, during the era of decolonization, several European countries reclassified certain regions as "overseas territories" or similar designations rather than colonies. For example, Portugal claimed that Goa was an overseas province, not a colony, arguing it was not subject to the decolonization process. This led to significant debates at the United Nations, with the USSR vetoing Portugal's attempts to reclaim Goa under the guise of decolonization.
Similarly, France has maintained territories like French Guiana (an overseas department), Saint Martin, and Tahiti (overseas collectivities). These regions often have a different status and level of protection under international law compared to traditional colonies.
Are there any legal distinctions between overseas territories and colonies under international law to back these country's claims on their overseas territories?

Isn't an overseas territory part of the country in question while a colony isn't?

Might want to consider that lot of the French overseas territories would be unviable economically and may not actually want independence.  Nor was, for example, St. Martin much of "someone else's land", as - being very lacking in fresh water - it had an extremely low, if any, native population prior to colonization, and those people (Arawaks or Caraibs) are now long gone.  Source:  I lived there for 8+ years.  Residents are also fully French citizens.

Not my DV, and I'm not super familiar with the framing of these [decolonization] discussions, but off the top of my head, one country can declare whatever they want (see e.g. Russia's declarations in re parts of Ukraine or China's declaration in re parts of India etc.) but unilateral declarations are usually hardly the end of such discussions.

Also, the title Q and the last para question differ. The title Q seems to assume the answer to the last-para Q is 'yes'.

Part of my question is "what makes a colony not part of the country and an overseas territory part of the country?"

The term that the UN uses to discuss such entities that might be entitled to independence is "Non-Self-Governing Territories". OTOH there's been a lot politicking what to include or not in that list. OTOH the UN has a "Special Committee on Decolonization" https://www.un.org/dppa/decolonization/en/c24/about which was established a long time ago https://history.state.gov/milestones/1945-1952/asia-and-africa

One can also avoid the decoloniziation process by ignoring it. See, e.g., Puerto Rico, which has neither full democratic rights in the country that claims it, nor independence.

The primary difficulty with doing that is democratic representation and consent of the governed. Residents of the French overseas departments are fully citizens of France regardless of ethnicity and vote in French elections, and their status has been determined by referendums among the local population; for instance, Mayotte became an overseas department after a referendum with decent turnout (comparable to US president elections, for instance) and quite high support for that status among voters, around 95%, not that there was not also some opposition. The argument for this is fairly simple: if two countries can voluntarily merge (as they can under international law), how could you force independence on a population that was opposed to it? The resulting independent country could easily just vote to merge. Note that the opposition to Mayotte being a part of France comes more from people who would like it to be part of Comoros, not from supporters of independence, although there are some French overseas collectivities with more equivocal support for continued French citizenship.
So to use this method to acquire territory, a country would have to persuade a majority of the residents of a territory to want to become part of their country, and would have to make them full citizens with voting rights; worst of all, they would probably have to continue to hold referenda in case sentiment turned in favor of independence, as has been the case in various French departments. This is not precisely conducive to the type of actions that most countries would engage in with respect to colonies, which is why most do not bother: Russia, for instance, invaded various parts of Ukraine before holding any referenda, and the USA does not give residents of Puerto Rico the same voting and other rights as residents of its 50 states; not coincidentally, both of those territories have been frequently described as colonies.

I'd also note that some of the "decolonization" demands are downright absurd. I.e. the UN wants Pitcairn Islands (pop. 50) to somehow "self govern".

@JonathanReez Interestingly as well, there were accusations of rampant child abuse by 1/3 of the adult males https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Pitcairn_Islands_sexual_assault_trial : The trial was repeatedly punctuated by legal challenges from island residents, who denied the island's colonial status

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yeah, presumably that trial would've been impossible if the island was 'independent'.

(+1) It's funny you would bring up Mayotte as it is one of the most problematic of all the French overseas territories because of the way the 1974 referendum was organized and interpreted. That's also why the issue is not independence but being reunited with the Comoros for the territory as whole did vote for independence back then and whether the vote should be counted island-by-island was hugely controversial.

@Relaxed - I only picked it because it was convenient and because it illustrated the issue with most current residents wanting to continue to be part of France—at this point, making Mayotte part of Comoros as it "should" be by some interpretations would certainly require using force against the people of Mayotte even if the rest of France decided to wash its hands of the matter—but your point is obviously well taken.

A colony is a form of military occupation. The colonizing nations sends settlers and troops to a region to establish long-term settlements, usually for the extraction of natural resources. These colonies are controlled and defended by the colonizing nation, whether against other national powers or indigenous natives, but neither the region itself nor its indigenous peoples are considered to part of the colonizing nation.
A territory is a formal but unincorporated part of the parent nation. Territorial land is considered to be 'owned' by the parent nation; territorial inhabitants (including indigenous peoples) are considered to be its citizens. Territories imply far greater commitments and costs for the parent nation, including defense, development of (non-utilitarian) infrastructure, representation in government, etc.
The colonial era ended largely because the World Wars sapped the resources of European nations, limiting their ability to control and suppress independence movements in colonized areas. Territorial status was generally only sought or granted in comparatively remote regions, because territorial status entails defense. No European nation wanted to be obligated to fight in the wars that would inevitably occur as newly-formed (ex-colonial) nations tested each other's borders.

"wars would inevitably occur" – why would they? Do you think the formerly colonised are just too uncivilised to engage with each other in a peacefull manner? In that case, the Charter of the OAU would prove you to be wrong and simply falling into the propaganda trap used to justify the colonies in the first place.

@ccprog: That's just typical IR behavior. Wherever states have contingent borders there is tension; whenever states are newly formed (lacking a historical justification for their boundaries), there is conflict. places like Tahiti or Samoa are largely exempt because there's no one near enough to squabble with. But the newly formed states in Africa and South East Asia had lots of neighbors who thought they might pick up some choice lands. Heck, even the early US had to fend off territory disputes with France, Spain, and even Canada.

@ccprog - Bold of you to think any nation on Earth can engage with its neighbors in a peaceful manner! There have been at least a dozen wars between African Union states since its creation, and other continents do not far fall behind.

Britain has one or two which would save them money to decolonise but are prevented by the residents insistence on remaining British - such as the Falkland Islands. And there is surely little chance of decolonising Gibraltar while its residents vote overwhelmingly to remain British. During WW2 it was of vital strategic importance, as together with Port Suez it ensured that the Axis powers had no means of entry or exit to the Mediterranean. It is of less significance today since Spain is a member of NATO anyway.

@WS2 - It's also a bit problematic because independence is not really an option for, at least, the Falklands/Malvinas, since Argentina would probably move to incorporate them against the wishes of the inhabitants, so it would be less "decolonized" than "recolonized." Gibraltar could probably negotiate independence as a country in the European Union if anyone in Spain or the UK (Gibraltar included) actually wanted that, though.

@WS2: the Falklands were also pretty important as a naval base during WWI. Less so during WW2 because Germany didn't have that many colonies by then. And money isn't everything. I'm sure Russia is losing money on Crimea & the Donbas.
